# Pagina PHP no se muestra correctamente

Tags: php, web, chrome

Tengo una pagina web en local y al ir a una de las páginas, esa no se muestra correctamente. En cambio en el hosting si que se ve correctament.

[image: Web desde navegador chrome]

Si hago click a ver código fuente, me aparece como que este comentada.

[image: Código Funete de navegador]

Me sería de mucha ayuda si me pudierais ayudar.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: que servidor web estas empleado para ejecutar el código PHP?

Comment: Estoy utilizando servidor MAMP

Comment: y el código mostrado si lo ejecutas desde dentro del servidor? por otro lado si tienes condigurado el servidor para ejecutar estas etiquetas de apertura abreviadas? `<? ?>` por que por defecto deberían ser así `<?php ?>`

Comment: Hola, ya lo he encontrado. Es lo que tu dices. En este servidor no tenia configurada la apertura <? Muchas gracias!!

Comment: De nada compañero

Answer (score 0):

Eso no es "una página web" (es decir, un documento HTML).

Es un script php. Para entendernos, un programa que está en un servidor y que, cuando se llama a determinada ruta de ese servidor, se ejecuta y genera una salida (normalmente el documento HTML, aunque puede ser de otro tipo).

Si abres el script php directamente desde el navegador, no se ejecuta, solo te muestra el texto del programa. Para que nos entendamos, es la misma diferencia entre ejecutar el word o abrir el fichero word.exe para ver el código binario.

Para generar el HTML en tu PC, instalate un servidor (normalmente Apache, investiga los stacks xampp/wampp/lampp), configúralo e invoca al script en tu servidor local.

Comment: Hola, He quitado la parte html. Por otro lado también tengo instalado el servidor apache(MAMP). Esta misma parte la tengo en hosting y me funciona correctamente.

Comment: La cuestión es que necesitas un servidor en local. Solo abrir el fichero no te va a ejecutar el script.